# Kubernetes run cronjob in wrong time

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

I have a schedule:
   `schedule: "0 10,14,18  * * *"`, I'd like to run this job in 10:00 am, 2:00pm, 6:00pm.

Since I located at UTC+8 timezone, this cronjob looks like not run as I expected.

Anyway to add a config for timezone?

Comment: why not specify time in UTC in cronjob? Like "0 0 2,6,10 * *"

Comment: In addition to what Vasily correctly pointed out, using timezone-based crontab would require that the cluster keep the [timezone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) up-to-date \[the latest update was in March, for example] with all the political theater that accompanies such a thing. That's not something traditionally associated with a container orchestration system

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From Kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/):

> Note: All CronJob schedule: times are based on the timezone of the master where the job is initiated.

You should be ok if you deploy your master in Hong Kong. GCP does not have a region in China (see [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones/))

You may consider deploying Kubernetes on Aws. Aws has regions in Beijing, China and Ningxia, China (see [here](https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/about-aws/china/))

Or may be on Azure (see [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/global-infrastructure/regions/))

With above setup in place, `schedule: "0 10,14,18 * * *"` should work

Comment: PS: The quote from the documentation is no longer true.

Comment: It uses the time zone of kube controller manager. If the kube controller manager runs in a container, it will be running based on the   localtime in that container, not the master/host OS.

Answer (score 7):

In Kubernetes v1.25, you can enable the `CronJobTimeZone` feature gate and set timezone by setting `spec.timeZone` to a valid time zone name.

For example, setting `spec.timeZone: "Australia/Melbourne"` makes Kubernetes to interpret the schedule relative to the `UTC+10 (STD)` timezone.

You can refer to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#time-zones) for more detailed info.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using managed GCP K8s, times are in UTC

[Docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs)

Answer (score 1):

In v1.22, there is a way to do it.

set something like `CRON_TZ=Asia/Tehran 0 0 * * *` as .spec.schedule value

> In addition, the CronJob schedule supports timezone handling, you can specify the timezone by adding "CRON_TZ=" at the beginning of the CronJob schedule, and it is recommended to always set CRON_TZ.

the document is at [https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#:~:text=In%20addition%2C%20the%20CronJob%20schedule,the%20kube%2Dcontroller%2Dmanager](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/#:%7E:text=In%20addition%2C%20the%20CronJob%20schedule,the%20kube%2Dcontroller%2Dmanager).

Answer (score 0):

For vanila kubernetes you can fix static pod. Add block

```
    volumeMounts:
    - name: localtime
      mountPath: /etc/localtime
      readOnly: true
volumes:
  - hostPath:
    path: /etc/localtime
    name: localtime
```

This make kube-controller-manager running in same timezone with host.

Comment: `Caution:
The v1 CronJob API does not officially support setting timezone as explained above.

Setting variables such as CRON_TZ or TZ is not officially supported by the Kubernetes project. CRON_TZ or TZ is an implementation detail of the internal library being used for parsing and calculating the next Job creation time. Any usage of it is not recommended in a production cluster.` seems like the suggestion has been adapted